# multiple ffmpeg instance with zmqsend

Tags: ffmpeg, zeromq

By any chance anyone would able to point to the right direction, I have multiple ffmpeg instances running on the server and i need to change the configuration (for example change the volume) on the fly while the ffmpeg instance is running. I found this https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-September/033777.html which the zmqsend is the tool do the job.

But how can i point the zmqsend sending the command to a specific ffmpeg instance?

I tried to run the zmqsend, but it got hanged.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different zmqPorts for your instances.